# Display Play Store listing in a dialog

Tags: android, google-play

How do you display a Play Store listing in a dialog? I have seen this when pairing a set of headphones that use the 'Google Fast Pair Service'. I got a notification saying 'Tap to download device app on Google Play and see all features'. Tapping this showed the store listing for 'My JBL Headphones' in a dialog. There was an Install button, and a details button which opened the full listing.

My app has nothing to do with headphones, I'm just using this workflow as an example. I expect the answer is some additional param to the `market://details?id=com.my.app` Intent, but I can't find any more info.

Fast Pair ref: https://developers.google.com/nearby/fast-pair/help#expected_behavior